# How does the EM algorithm work in Bayesian regression?

Tags: regression, bayesian, inference, algorithms, expectation-maximization

I have problem distinguishing between the latent variables $z_i$ and the parameters $\theta_i$ in EM algorithm. Suppose we have the hierarchical priors

\begin{aligned}
\beta|\tau,\omega &\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\tau\,\omega) \\[.5em]
\tau &\sim \text{Gamma}(a,1) \enspace \\[.5em]
\omega &\sim \text{Inv-Gamma}(b,1) \enspace .
\end{aligned}

In a paper I have read, the latent variables $z_i$ are chosen to be $\{\beta,\tau,\omega\}$ while the hyperparameters $\theta_i$ are $\{a,b\}$.

However, [in other models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134207/question-on-how-to-use-em-to-estimate-parameters-of-this-model?rq=1), $\beta$ is chosen as a member of $\theta_i$.

My question is how do we choose $\theta_i$ and $z_i$? Are we free to choose?

Also, why is it that $\theta$ doesn't appear in [Variational Inference](https://fabiandablander.com/r/Variational-Inference.html) but appears in the [Variational EM](https://chrischoy.github.io/research/Expectation-Maximization-and-Variational-Inference/).

Comment: I worry that there are a number of misunderstandings here. Where do you ever see that " is chosen as a member of " or that VI is performed without parameters?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, if you check the answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134207/question-on-how-to-use-em-to-estimate-parameters-of-this-model?rq=1 $\beta$ is chosen as $\theta_i$ and $w_i$ as latent variable.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, here https://fabiandablander.com/r/Variational-Inference.html only $z_i$ appears without $\theta$.

Comment: In the first case—not every use of a symbol in mathematics means the same thing. In the linked question, $\beta$ are the parameters of the linear model. They're shared across all data points. Up above, there's one $\beta$ per data point. As for your second question—they just chose not to write the $\theta$ for brevity.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, I am not sure what you mean, could you explain more please.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, The two models look the same....no?